# how to determine space in a post method while form processing?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, whitespace, texttrimming

I am getting a textbox value from a form, i which the customer inputs his full name.

So it is `FirstName` and `LastName`, Now when he inputes his/her name in the textbox the value is sent through `$_POST` and get stored in a variable `$name`.

Now i have two fields in my database, one is `first_name` and another is `last_name`.

The `last_name` will never contain any value which includes space.

For example: it cant be `Doe Doe`, it has to be `Doe` only.

Where as in `first_name` field, spaces are allowed, For example user name could be `John` or `John Mennon`.

Therefore we can say that we have a `first_name` in mysql table field `John Mennon` and `last_name` be `Doe`.

Now when user input this value as `John Mennon Doe`, i want to get the last value after spaces as my `last_name` i.e. `Doe` and remain all to be my `first_name` i.e. `John Mennon`.

How can i get these two values out of the submitted value stored in a variable called `$name`?

As after getting these values i'll match them both separately from mysql database and let user do the other job.

Comment: i don't think it is a good idea to split the whole name into arbitrary "first" and "last" - http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2271.html

Comment: What if Denise van Outen wants to sign up?

Comment: You might want to accept the answer, that worked for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$parts = explode(' ', trim($_POST['name']));
$lastName = array_pop($parts);
$firstName = implode(' ', $parts);
```

Comment: And what if my name were "Vincent van Gogh"? This would store my first name as being "Vincent van" and my lastname as being "Gogh" which is incorrect... See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9965312/786814

Answer (score 2):

Though the other answers provide correct technical solutions to your problem, no one is mentioning best practice.

Best practice is to [avoid making assumptions about people's names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). What if my name were "Vincent van Gogh"? How do you tell what is my first name and what is my last name? Well... you can't. I could also be called "Prince" (the artist) which raises the same problem...

After encountering this issue many times with software I've taken over, I've decided to never again make this mistake and always store names as one field in my database.

It makes no difference for search (whether you be using MySQL Fulltext searches or Solr), and if you want to display a nickname for the user, just ask them for one!

Comment: I think this could be root lesson, i'll take care of it.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use strrpos to get the last index of space in your string and then use substr to get first_name and last_name

A good example of strrpos is at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Answer (score 1):

Gotta love the regular expressions:

```
if (preg_match("~^((\w+\s*)+)\s+(\w+)$~", trim($_POST["name"]), $match))
{
    $firstName = $match[1];
    $lastName = $match[3];
}
else
    ; // invalid input format
```

I would just ask the user for his first and last name seperately, as parsing them is generally very tricky.

Just for the fun I added some kind of name prefix detection:

```
if (preg_match("~^(([A-Z]\w+\s+)+)(([a-z]+\s+)?\w+)$~", trim($_POST["name"]), $match))
{
    $firstName = trim($match[1]);
    $lastName = $match[3];
}
else
    // invalid input format
```

I assumed that those prefixes like "van" will be written in lower case letters. So any of the name's parts right before the last name that start with a lower case letter are considered a prexix and will be included in the last name.

For example `Denise Monique van Outen` will be split into `Denise Monique` and `van Outen`.

Comment: Assumptions are the root of all evil. This will fail in numerous scenarios (including but not limited to using uppercase letters). See why this isn't a good approach here: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: It's just what OP asked for. "Assumptions are the root of all evil." what a meaningless statement to say. We cannot solve all problems at ones so we need to create assumtions to have other people know what sub problem we are solving. Btw are those OP's assumtions, not mine. Why would you post this to this answer instead of OP's question?

Comment: ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) Imo, so are assumptions; just my way of saying I think it's a bad thing for the industry and community in general. I posted that under your answer cause you wrote _"I assumed that those prefixes like 'van' would be in lower case letters"_. As you'll notice, I've tried to point what I believe to be a bad approach under each answer, not just yours.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I see this completely differently.